# How to check if the file name contains specific set of characters in ksh?

Tags: shell, ksh

I have lot of files in one sub directory. I have to check if the file name contains specific set of characters.

For Example

1.I have files like xyz.xml,jkxyz.xml,bxyz.xml,jkl.xml in one subdirectory
Dir-Path of the directory

```
     #!/bin/ksh
     for b in $Dir/*
     do
     if [ "$b" = * "$Dir/xyz" * ]
     then
     echo "Exist"
     else
     echo "Not Exist"
     fi
     done
```

3.IF the file name contains xyz it should return exist otherwise it should return not exist.

4.I did this. But it doesn't return the output of true condition

5.Anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

In ksh, you can do glob matching inside `[[...]]` with the `==` operator:

```sh
if [[ "$b" == *xyz* ]]
```

Note, no spaces on the "inside" of the wildcard characters.

The `case` statement works here too, it does pattern matching:

```sh
case "$b" in 
  *xyz*) echo Exist ;;
  *)     echo Not Exist ;;
esac
```

---

However, if you want to iterate over "xyz" files in $Dir, you can just do

```sh
for file in "$Dir"/*xyz*; do
    do_stuff_with "$file"
done
```